# How to change id or each field by using jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, clone

i want the result must to be like,

```
<tr class="tr_cond"> 
<td>BLA</td>
<td>BLA</td>
<td>BLA</td>
<td>BLA</td>
<td><input type="button" class="tr_condition" value="+" name="add"></td>
</tr>
<tr class="tr_cond" id="tablCond1"> 
<td id="tablCond1>BLA</td>
<td id="colCond1>BLA</td>
<td id="operCond1>BLA</td>
<td id="valCond1>BLA</td>
<td><input type="button" class="tr_condition" value="+" name="add"></td>
</tr>
<tr class="tr_cond"> 
<td id="tablCond2>BLA</td>
<td id="colCond2>BLA</td>
<td id="operCond2>BLA</td>
<td id="valCond2>BLA</td>
<td><input type="button" class="tr_condition" value="+" name="add"></td>
</tr>
<tr class="tr_cond"> 
<td id="tablCond3>BLA</td>
<td id="colCond3>BLA</td>
<td id="operlCond3>BLA</td>
<td id="valCond3>BLA</td>
<td><input type="button" class="tr_condition" value="+" name="add"></td>
</tr>
```

And the jQuery is,

```
$(".tr_condition").live('click', CloneCondition);
var cloneCount = 1;
function CloneCondition(){
    $(this).closest('.tr_cond')
        .clone()
        .attr('id', 'tablCond'+ cloneCount++)
        .insertAfter(".tr_cond:last"); 
}
```

which is working to clone the row, but I want to change the id of those fields inside the row, but this only changes the id of the row.

Comment: please format your code

Comment: well, you're almost there.. what seems to stop you from doing it?

Comment: see how your code looks more answerable without all your `<php>`s ?

Comment: sorry for post unformatted code.. thnx roXon,  i dunno how to change all the fields id from the row. here this code changes the id of the <tr>

Comment: FYI, since version 1.7 jQuery has the .on() function, which replaces .live().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To which field you want to add an `ID` ? to the `input` ?
In the meanwhile:

**Use the `.on()` method** for elements that are dynamically added to the document

http://jsbin.com/uharaw/5/edit

```
$("table").on('click', '.tr_condition', CloneCondition);

var addIDs = ['tabl','col','oper','val'];
var cloneCount = 0;

function CloneCondition(){

    cloneCount++;

    $(this).closest('.tr_cond')
        .clone()
        .insertAfter(".tr_cond:last");

    // after clone is done let's go for the last (new) one
    $('.tr_cond:last td').not(':last').each(function(i){
       $(this).attr('id', addIDs[i] +'Cond'+ cloneCount);
    });

}
```

which after a couple of clicks results in:

```
<tr class="tr_cond"> 
    <td>BLA</td>
    <td>BLA</td>
    <td>BLA</td>
    <td>BLA</td>
    <td><input name="add" value="+" class="tr_condition" type="button"></td>
</tr>
<tr class="tr_cond"> 
    <td id="tablCond1">BLA</td>
    <td id="colCond1">BLA</td>
    <td id="operCond1">BLA</td>
    <td id="valCond1">BLA</td>
    <td><input name="add" value="+" class="tr_condition" type="button"></td>
</tr>
<tr class="tr_cond"> 
    <td id="tablCond2">BLA</td>
    <td id="colCond2">BLA</td>
    <td id="operCond2">BLA</td>
    <td id="valCond2">BLA</td>
    <td><input name="add" value="+" class="tr_condition" type="button"></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: i can get this result even by using .live but i want to increment th id of <td> not the id of <tr>

Comment: @sher as you can see from my example I'm not changing the `TR` ID... And your input texts does not have any ID to change... Can you try to explain?

Comment: see the coding in bold leters.. i wana change tht id.. how to do tht?? the id and name of the original n cloned were same
<tr class="tr_cond">
<td>
<td>
<select **id="colCond" name="colCond">**
</td>
<td>
<td>
<td>
</tr>
<tr id="tablCond0" class="tr_cond">
<td id="tablCond1">
<td id="colCond1">
<select **id="colCond" name="colCond">**

Comment: @sher I'm sorry, This is becoming really messy. I suggest you to ask a new question.

Answer (score 1):

try this now .....

```
$(".tr_condition").live('click', CloneCondition);
var cloneCount = 1;
function CloneCondition(){

  $("tr td:nth-child(1)").attr("id","your id");
}
```